# Can connect through SSTP but not PPTP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, pptp, rras, sstp

I have a window server 2008 r2 box behind a a Netgear AC1750 router. I've set up RRAS for a VPN and can successfully connect using SSTP, but if I try to connect to the VPN using PPTP I get a timeout error.  I don't have an error message on my devices, it just says timeout. I've got 20 open PPTP ports in RRAS, on my router I've got port 1723 open, and my server firewall is allowing 1723 and protocol 47. So what gives? I feel like I'm missing something simple here, and I'd like to be able to connect my android devices to the VPN but I'm stuck on this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Startup tcpdump/wireshark/etc and perform captures to isolate the issue to which device is causing the problem.  If the device is your Netgear router, then contact Netgear support maybe?  I doubt that router is going to be able to support this though.  You might need to upgrade to a router that isn't meant as upper-end consumer gear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it appears the Netgear AC1750 does not support PPTP Passthrough or PPTP NAT Traversal.

Neither is mentioned in the documentation and this comparison says so explicitly:

http://routers.findthebest.com/compare/1-43/ASUS-RT-AC66U-802-11ac-vs-NetGear-AC-1750-R6300